# Learning JavaScript - for-in statement with a max. result

Tags: javascript, navigator, for-in-loop

I'm reading a book about JS, and I'm stuck with one of the excercises.

I wrote a for-in to display the browser properties.

```
    for (var i in navigator) {

    document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML += i + ': ' + navigator[i] + '<br />';
};
```

Now is the question how can I display only the first 10 of the navigator properties?

Thnx for helping me out!

Comment: write an if statement which checks if `i` is less than 10 and encapsulate your innerHTML statement inside of it.

Comment: If you know how many time you want to loop, use a `for` loop, not a `for-in`.

Comment: How about having some variable to count the instances, you already gave to output and just stop the output, if that number hits 10?

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is obviously a very beginner, and we all struggled with frustrating things like this when we started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an object, and unlike an array objects don't have a "length" property that lets you easily run a loop over them.  There are lots of ways to do this, but the easiest way to understand when you're learning is to create a "counter" variable outside expression and check to see if its true:

```
var counter = 0;

for (var i in navigator) 
{
    if ( counter <= 10 ) 
    {
       document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML += i + ': ' + navigator[i] + '<br />';
       counter = counter + 1;
    }
};
```

There are other ways to cause the expression to stop, as mentioned above, but this (for me) was the easiest way to think about things when I started

Answer (score 1):

Increment a counter, quit the loop when it hits 10

```
var i = 0;
for (var k in navigator) {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML += i + ', ' + k + ': ' + navigator[k] + '<br />';
    if (i === 10) 
        break;
};
```